# SP2010 - Workflow to change field status to "Expired" if field Expiry Date is less than Today

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, pause

I can't seems to figure-out how to make the below workflow works.

I have a simple lists that has an ID expiration date and A status field to show if "Active" or "Expired" based on the ID Expiration date.

Basically the workflow should check the "ID Expiration Date" daily and if it is **greater than** [Today] date, it will set the Status field value to "Active" and "Expired" if **less than** [Today] date.

Your help is much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the workflow Start Options?

The workflow only run when it is triggered, it will not run daily by default.
For your requirement, you can use **Information Management Policy** to trigger your workflow. You can create a retention rule and based on the "ID Expiration Date" to trigger your workflow. And in your workflow, you could just add actions to update the fields that you want.

[Using The Information Management Policy (Specifically The Retention Policy) In SharePoint 2010](https://sharepointduffbert.com/2014/07/17/using-the-information-management-policy-specifically-the-retention-policy-in-sharepoint-2010/)